# Marker on the center of map after drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I implement google map on my website. User can drag the marker and get coordinates. It's working fine but requirement is that when user drag marker, after drag marker should come on the center of the map window or if user drag map, then for this case marker also come to the center of map window.

I have the following code which is working for only drag marker on the map, 
but I don't know where to add the function or code that move the marker on the center of map window after drag.

That code is written below:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById('dragStatus').innerHTML = '<p> Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(4) + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(4) + '</p>';
    var point = marker.getPosition();
       map.panTo(point);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragstart', function (evt) {
    //-------------
    //------------
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ANJYR/6xq6pujk/

Comment: You want to center the map on the marker when the drag ends? Or move the marker to the center of the map? This is unclear. But it sounds weird to be able to move a marker around to get the coordinates and that once it's done the marker would move itself to the center of the map.

Comment: Doesn't sound weird at all; the OP wants to center the map if the marker is set to a new position...Cheers ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is (I think) an easier solution... Or I didn't quite get what you want to achieve.

```
//Dragable Marker In Google Map....

var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.013803, -71.551498);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapBox'), {
    zoom: 18,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
});

var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: center,
    draggable: true,
    map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function () {
    map.setCenter(this.getPosition()); // Set map center to marker position
    updatePosition(this.getPosition().lat(), this.getPosition().lng()); // update position display
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
    myMarker.setPosition(this.getCenter()); // set marker position to map center
    updatePosition(this.getCenter().lat(), this.getCenter().lng()); // update position display
});

function updatePosition(lat, lng) {
    document.getElementById('dragStatus').innerHTML = '<p> Current Lat: ' + lat.toFixed(4) + ' Current Lng: ' + lng.toFixed(4) + '</p>';
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/5xd1Lbpc/6/)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Just add this piece of code:

```
var point = myMarker.getPosition(); //instead of marker.getPosition();
map.setCenter(point); //set the center of the map based on myMarker
```

> **Update: Marker centered on map after dragging**
>
> About the `idle` event: This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming.

```
//Add listener on idle event
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'idle',function(){
  if(!this.get('dragging') && this.get('oldCenter') && this.get('oldCenter')!==this.getCenter()) {
    //Here i set the marker position with map.getCenter data
    myMarker.setPosition(this.getCenter());
  }
  if(!this.get('dragging')){
   this.set('oldCenter',this.getCenter())
  }
});

//Add listener on dragstart, set map dragging to true
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'dragstart',function(){
  this.set('dragging',true);          
});

//Add listener on dragend, set map dragging to false
//And trigger the idle listener
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'dragend',function(){
  this.set('dragging',false);
  google.maps.event.trigger(this,'idle',{});
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/5xd1Lbpc/

Comment: nice work. thank you. 1 more thing if i drag map, then for this case can marker also come to the center of map window.

Comment: Please explain your solution. Either with text or comments in your code. Thank you.

Comment: Comments added to the code...I don't understand why the downvote, since the original question is just about centering the marker...but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Thank you for editing, but I don't see why you would need all that stuff to achieve that? Down-vote removed since you edited your answer.

Comment: Post your answer and you'll get my upvote...no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:     https://jsfiddle.net/6xq6pujk/5/

```
//Dragable Marker In Google Map....


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapBox'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.6139, 77.2090),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(28.6139, 77.2090),
    draggable: true
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById('dragStatus').innerHTML = '<p> Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(4) + ' Current Lng: ' +  + '</p>';
     var x = evt.latLng.lat();
    var y = evt.latLng.lng();

    var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
    myMarker.setPosition(newLatLng);


    // using global variable:
    map.panTo(newLatLng);


});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
    //-------------
    //------------


});


map.setCenter(myMarker.position);
myMarker.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(f=0; f<Data.length; f++)
                {           
                            /*var p = Data[f];
                            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p[0], p[1]);
                            bounds.extend(latlng);*/
                             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position:  new google.maps.LatLng(Data[f][0], Data[f][1]),
                                map: map,
                                draggable:<?php  echo $dragger; ?>,
                                icon: iconBase
                              });

                       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', (function(marker, f) {
                        return  function()
                        {
                               if(confirm("Are you sure you want to change lat/lng?")){   
                            var park_id = ID[f];
                            var lat = this.getPosition().lat();
                            var lng = this.getPosition().lng();
                                    $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>Admin/updateParkid", 
                              data: {park_id: park_id, latitude: lat, longitude: lng},
                              dataType: '',
                              success: function(result){
                                alert(result);

                                //marker.setIcon(iconBase);
                                        }
                              });            
                            } }
                         })(marker, f));
```

Comment: where markers above must be having database latitude & longitude to show markers on map

Comment: Hi There, Your answer could do with more supporting information: its just the block of code. Why is there now a dependency on php when the original question did not suggest they where even using PHP?. Does your answer provide any benefits over the other three answers already provided, maybe one that is not obvious without studying the code in detail?

Comment: may be, I have only provided answer for the drag & change coordinates & coordinated shown are like according to changed new coordinates in which were saved in database through ajax in php & retrieved through php & then embed in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use `$event` as value to `dragEnd` event.

```
    <agm-marker
            (markerClick)="clickedMarker()"
            [latitude]="lat"
            [longitude]="lng"
            [markerDraggable]=true
            (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd($event)">
    </agm-marker>
```