# Keep marker/pin in the middle of the map while dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want the marker/pin to scroll around and be in the center of the map while the user is dragging around the map. I have a simple jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/5xd1Lbpc/6/) where the pin will drop to the center of the map when the user stops dragging, but I want the pin to move with the dragging.

Google Maps JS

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.013803, -71.551498);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapBox'), {
    zoom: 18,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
});

var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: center,
    draggable: true,
    map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function () {
    map.setCenter(this.getPosition()); // Set map center to marker position
    updatePosition(this.getPosition().lat(), this.getPosition().lng()); // update position display
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
    myMarker.setPosition(this.getCenter()); // set marker position to map center
    updatePosition(this.getCenter().lat(), this.getCenter().lng()); // update position display
});

function updatePosition(lat, lng) {
    document.getElementById('dragStatus').innerHTML = '<p> Current Lat: ' + lat.toFixed(4) + ' Current Lng: ' + lng.toFixed(4) + '</p>';
}
```

HTML

```
<div id='mapBox'></div>
```

Any ideas or thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want the pin to remain static in the centre of the map, even when the user is dragging the map around?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if that wasn't clear. I want it just to remain static in the middle while the user is dragging the map around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Marker on the center of map after drag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893146/marker-on-the-center-of-map-after-drag)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed marker in center and drag map to get lat,long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722930/fixed-marker-in-center-and-drag-map-to-get-lat-long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add  this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function () {
  myMarker.setPosition(this.getCenter()); // set marker position to map center
   updatePosition(this.getCenter().lat(), this.getCenter().lng()); // update position display
});
```

see  http://jsfiddle.net/gbqqzonr/

```
//Dragable Marker In Google Map....

var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.013803, -71.551498);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapBox'), {
    zoom: 18,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
});

var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: center,
    draggable: true,
    map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function () {
    map.setCenter(this.getPosition()); // Set map center to marker position
    updatePosition(this.getPosition().lat(), this.getPosition().lng()); // update position display
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function () {
    myMarker.setPosition(this.getCenter()); // set marker position to map center
    updatePosition(this.getCenter().lat(), this.getCenter().lng()); // update position display
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
    myMarker.setPosition(this.getCenter()); // set marker position to map center
    updatePosition(this.getCenter().lat(), this.getCenter().lng()); // update position display
});

function updatePosition(lat, lng) {
    document.getElementById('dragStatus').innerHTML = '<p> Current Lat: ' + lat.toFixed(4) + ' Current Lng: ' + lng.toFixed(4) + '</p>';
}
```

Comment: You could improve performance slightly by assigning `this.getCenter()` to a variable in the map's drag listener, rather than calling it 3 times.

Answer (score 7):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edcxsw1/5xd1Lbpc/10/)

To reduce flicker, you can put an absolutely positioned marker over top of the map directly in the center. Then you can use `getCenter()` to retrieve the actual position on the map.

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
#mapBox {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
#marker {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 40px);
    left: calc(50% - 40px);
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(30,144,255,0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="mapBox"></div>
    <div id="marker"></div>
</div>
<div id="dragStatus"></div>
```

JS:

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.013803, -71.551498);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapBox'), {
    zoom: 18,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function() {
  loc(map);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function () {
  loc(map);
});

function loc(map) {
    var x = map.getCenter();
    document.getElementById('dragStatus').innerHTML = x.lat() + ', ' + x.lng();
}
```

Other Useful Answers:

[Is there a way to Fix a Google Maps Marker to the Center of its Map always?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327254/is-there-a-way-to-fix-a-google-maps-marker-to-the-center-of-its-map-always)