# Keep Marker Pin in center will I drag map

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, ionic4

I am building a use case where I am using google maps API using the IONIC framework.

After displaying the map in the page with the marker pin in the location(lat,lng), I need to allow the user to drag the map, keeping the pin fixed so that they can pinpoint their address, on drag stop i need to fetch the lat,lang of the point and get address of the point and display in UI. How can I achieve this?

following is the code I have used to display the map with the PIN.

```
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {

this.map = new google.maps.Map(
  this.mapNativeElement.nativeElement,
  {
    center: { lat: 17.455841, lng: 78.335507 },
    zoom: 16,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  }
);

this.marker = new google.maps.Marker(
  {
    map: this.map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: { lat: 17.455841, lng: 78.335507 }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
this.marker = new google.maps.Marker(
{
  map: this.map,
  draggable: true,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  position: { lat: 17.455841, lng: 78.335507 }
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', () => {
    this.map.setCenter(this.map.getPosition()); 
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function () {
    myMarker.setPosition(this.getCenter()); 
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
    myMarker.setPosition(this.getCenter()); 
});
```

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36896072/5613720) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Though the previous answer is correct and does the job, the problem still persists as the google map marker (at times when moved quickly) does not necessarily come to the center of the map.

On further research, I found that the better solution to achieve this use-case would be to keep a marker separate marker at the center of the div and use map.getCenter() to get the location whenever required.

this way the only event listener to be added would be dragend.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', (function () {
        var l = map.getCenter();
        //marker.setPosition(l);
        console.log("get center", l);
        this.updatePosition(l.lat(), l.lng());
      }).bind(this));
    }

#map {
  height: 60%;
  position: relative;
}

#map:after {
  width: 44px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -40px 0 0 -11px;
  background: url("../../assets/icon/pin.png");
  background-size: 44px 50px;
```

}

> Pro tip: You can also use a gif instead of png. Makes the map come
>   alive.